# Grading on the graded direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-modules, graded-rings

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666849/graded-direct-products).

> Probably it's obvious but could you tell me what is the grading on the graded direct product?

I was thinking about $^*\Pi M^i=\oplus_j(\Pi_i M^i_j)$ where $M^i_j$ is the degree $j$-part of $M^i$, but I couldn't prove it and I'm not sure I'm correct, especially because if $R=M^i=k[x]$, then $(1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots)$ seems to belong to the graded direct product but I don't think it belongs to $\oplus_j(\Pi_i M^i_j)$.

Comment: When I say what is the grading on the graded direct product I mean what is the grading on $^*\Pi M^i$.

Comment: What means $^*\Pi M$ for you? Usually this denotes the graded direct product which is by definition $\oplus_j(\Pi_i M^i_j)$. Maybe you use another definition: $^*\Pi M$ is the submodule of $\Pi M_i$ generated by the sequences $(x_i)$ with $x_i$ homogeneous, and want to know if they coincide.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. My definition of $^*\Pi M_i$ is in the link provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've misunderstood the definition of $^*\Pi M_i$ in Bruns and Herzog. When write  $^*\Pi M_i$ is "the submodule of $\Pi M_i$ generated by the sequences $(x_i)$ with $x_i$ homogeneous" you should add "of degree $n$, $n\in\mathbb Z$", that is, all $x_i$ have the same degree, and thus their definition coincides (how else?) with $\oplus_j(\Pi_i M^i_j)$.